# Python schedule library some time works some time not, any ide why?

Tags: python

Ok!
I messing with the schedule module for python.
I wrote a project some days ago where the schedule is working like charm.

Today I started a new and simple project also with the schedule module, but I cant figure out why it is not working.

Practically, I opened my old but working project, and made change in the main function of the program, the schedule stuff in my program wasn't changed.

After saving my "new project" under a different name and I run my code, I got this error:
**AttributeError: module 'schedule' has no attribute 'every'**

Ok, I rechecked every bit of my code, I didn't found any problem but it wont run.

I started a complete new project and set up everything new, but with the same error.
Here is my new schedule code, and I can't find any reason why I got the error.

```
import schedule
import time


def show_name():
    print("Test ok every 4 sec.")


schedule.every(4).seconds.do(show_name)

while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Any idea what the hack is going on?

But If I load my "original", old code it is working.

I use PyCharm as my IDE.

Thanks for any suggestion and help.

Update:
python version is 3.9.7
schedule version is 1.1.0
OS Win10 x64
No virtual machine environment.

Comment: I tested with python 3.9.9 and schedule 1.1.0. It worked without any problem. What is your python and schedule version? Are you using a virtual environment?

Answer (score 0):

From the package [FAQ](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-every) section:

> This happens if your code imports the wrong schedule module. Make sure you don’t have a schedule.py file in your project that overrides the schedule module provided by this library.

Do you happen to have a file named `schedule.py` in your folder?

Comment: I don't have a schedule.py in my folder where my project is sitting.